# Transparent background in Sites Apps Script with HtmlService

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sites

There is a similar question in:
[Google App Script background transparent with HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492581/google-app-script-background-transparent-with-htmlservice)
with no satisfactory answer.

In my situation, I have this simple Apps Script embedded in Google Sites:

CODE.GS

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
    .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

PAGE.HTML

```html
<html>
  <body style="background-color:transparent">
    How do I make it<br/>transparent ?
  </body>
</html>
```

resulting in a page that looks like this:

https://sites.google.com/site/seanpj01/backtest

Even if the trick of setting

```html
<body style="background-color:transparent">
```

works if implemented as a straight XML-wrapped gadget, it fails in this situation (I suspect CAJA). There is a discussion on this problem here:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/KU9nSz37c6U

but again, to no avail.