# Set Google Apps Script Background in Google sites

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, google-sites-2016

I've run into an issue with embedding a Google Apps Script HTML into my Google Site in that the default white background doesn't fit with the theme of the website.

Is it at all possible to get the Google Apps Script HTML to have a transparent background or change the background colour of the Google Apps Script to suite it more? I've done alot of research but I have yet to find anyone who has found a solution to this issue.

Comment: related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166366/how-can-i-integrate-google-script-html-with-a-transparent-background-as-iframe), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309186/transparent-background-in-sites-apps-script-with-htmlservice)

Comment: Hi Kos, neither of those "related" links actually answer the question, one is over 8 years old and the other doesn't fit the description either.

Comment: I just embed it as html

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Apps Script HTML". Have you create a web application? What is the color that you want to use?

Comment: Ideally I wanted to make it transparent on the Google Site (As an embedded web application) but if that isn't feasible then a dark green could work Ruben.

Answer (score 1):

By default, HtmlElements have a transparent background, but Google Apps Script web app embeds the content generated by the HtmlService in an iFrame which has an element with the background set as white. This element can't be accessed from Google Apps Script.

The workaround is to inspect the Google Sites page that will contain the embedded element and set the background color of the Google Apps Script web app to that color. Let say that your site has a `green` background, the following shows one way to set the background color of the body element of the Google Apps Script web app to `green`:

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Related

- [Google App Script background transparent with HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16492581/1595451)
- [Transparent Iframe Background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68332405/1595451)