# Google sites script background color change + DST

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a very small 'Last Updated' script I would like for the background to be either transparent or of the surrounding color. I've looked for awhile now how to go about inserting this into the script itself but am at a loss. Maybe I'm looking at it incorrectly:

```
function doGet(e){
  var app= UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  var updated = Utilities.formatDate(page.getLastUpdated(), "Etc/GMT+4", 
"EEE - MMM d, yyyy,  hh:mm:ss a");
  app.add(app.createHTML('Last Updated: ' + updated));
    return app;
}
```

Results in this:

[image]

Wondering if there's a way to have the script background appear as grey instead of white.

Additionally (but not as important), I noticed by entering the timezone (EST) - it does not account for DST so the Last Updated time was an hour off.  Had to use GMT+4 to compensate.  Is there a way to 'enable' DST, or will I need to adjust the script twice a year?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var app= UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  var updated = Utilities.formatDate(page.getLastUpdated(), "Etc/GMT+4", 
"EEE - MM, dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a");

app.add(app.createHTML('Last Update: + update'));
return app;
}
```

for color background try the below code

uiApp.createApplication().setStyleAttribute("background","transparent")

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Where's the background color piece? Looks like only adjustments were the date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UiApp.createApplication().setStyleAttribute("background","transparent")` to create a transparent background. However based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service), the UI service was deprecated and to create user interfaces, use the HTML service instead. Refer with this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492581/google-app-script-background-transparent-with-htmlservice).